# asp-page tag element is redirecting back to the same page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I am working on a website using razor. I am using taghelper, asp-page, but the link is just redirecting to itself. When I look at the page source, the url is empty.

```
@page
@model PMSX.WebApp.Pages.Stock.ListModel
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

```
<div class="row">  
    <div class="col-6">  
        <h2 class="text-info">Stock List</h2>  
    </div>  

</div>  

<table>
<tr class="table-secondary">  
    <th>  
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.StockList[0].Symbol)  
    </th>  
    <th>  
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.StockList[0].StockName)  
    </th>  
    <th>  
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.StockList[0].Price)   
    </th>  

</tr>  

@foreach(var stock in Model.StockList)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a asp-page="./Stock/" asp-route-id="@stock.Symbol">
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => stock.Symbol) 
            </a>
        </td>  
        <td>  
            <a asp-page="./Stock/" asp-route-id="@stock.Symbol">
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => stock.StockName)
            </a> 
        </td>  
        <td>  
            <a asp-page="./Stock/" asp-route-id="@stock.Symbol">
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => stock.Price)  
            </a>
        </td>  
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

When I click on the link, it just redirect back to the same page, because the href in the "a" tag is empty.

Comment: Do you have a Stock page (Stock.cshtml and Stock.cshtml.cs)? Is the code you posted inside the Stock.cshtml?

Comment: Yes, I have cshtml and cshtml.cs. This is the code I posted in .cshtml

Comment: What is your directory structure like, does a Stock folder contain List Page and Stock Page?

Comment: My Stock folder contains a List Page and an Index page.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Page didn't exist. I am still learning!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure you have `Stock.cshtml` and `Stock.cshtml.cs`.There is no problem with your code. Based on your question, it seems that you do not have a `Stock` Page.

Below is my test code,it works fine:

List.cshtml.cs:

```
public class ListModel : PageModel
{
    public List<StockList> stockLists { get; set; }
    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        stockLists = new List<StockList>();
        stockLists.Add(new StockList { Symbol = "TestSymblo", StockName = "TestStockName", Price = "TestPrice" });
        return Page();
    }
}
public class StockList
{ 
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public string StockName { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
}
```

List.cshtml:

```
@page
@model _20220719011.Pages.Stock.ListModel

<div class="row">  
    <div class="col-6">  
        <h2 class="text-info">Stock List</h2>  
    </div>  

</div>  

<table>
<tr class="table-secondary">  
    <th>  
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.stockLists[0].Symbol)  
    </th>  
    <th>  
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.stockLists[0].StockName)  
    </th>  
    <th>  
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.stockLists[0].Price)   
    </th>  

</tr>  

@foreach(var stock in Model.stockLists)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a asp-page="./Stock/" asp-route-id="@stock.Symbol">
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => stock.Symbol) 
            </a>
        </td>  
        <td>  
            <a asp-page="./Stock/" asp-route-id="@stock.Symbol">
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => stock.StockName)
            </a> 
        </td>  
        <td>  
            <a asp-page="./Stock/" asp-route-id="@stock.Symbol">
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => stock.Price)  
            </a>
        </td>  
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Stock.cshtml.cs:

```
public class StockModel : PageModel
{
    public string test { get; set; }
    public IActionResult OnGet(string id)
    {
        test = id;
        return Page();
    }
}
```

Stock.cshtml:

```
@page
@model _20220719011.Pages.Stock.StockModel

<h2>@Model.test</h2>
```

Test Result:

[image]
[image]